# How to fill in a ModelForm within django view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using a Django form that will be filled out multiple times by the same user. I would like to populate the form with data from previous submissions (I have a **Foreignkey to the user** that will be filling out the form), however, it is important that this is done server side as to not have the auto-populated data accessible user-side.

Is there a way to fill in specific fields that I don't want filled out again by the user within views.py before calling is_valid?

**Views.py:**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ptForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            report = form.save(commit=False)
            report.pt_user = request.user
            report.save()
            form = ptForm()
        else:
            print(messages.error(request, "Error"))
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = ptForm()
    context = {'form': form,
    'ptz_data': pt_data.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: I want the fields to auto-populate the new form however

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Along with the advice Lewis gave me, another SO question was helpful and I came to the following answer. The trick is to request.POST.copy(), alter that variable, and then plug it back into your form (mine was form = ptForm(updated_request):

```
def home(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                latest_entry = pt_data.objects.filter(pt_user=request.user).latest('id')
                updated_request = request.POST.copy()
                updated_request.update({
                'pt_sex': latest_entry.pt_sex,
                'pt_age': latest_entry.pt_age,})

                form = ptForm(updated_request)
            except:
                form = ptForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                report = form.save(commit=False)
                report.pt_user = request.user
                report.save()
                form = ptForm()
            else:
                print(messages.error(request, "Error"))
                print(form.errors)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the latest entry via:

```py
latest_entry = pt_data.objects.filter(pt_user=request.user).latest('id')
```

**Method 1:** *Prefill data into form for user to see.*

Then use the forms `initial` keyword to provide data into the form in your `GET` request. By filling it with the `latest_entry` attributes.

```py
else:
   form = ptForm(initial={...})
```

Without context on what your form structure is I cannot provide the code for this but the usage on this can be found in the [**Django Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

**Method 2:** *Update values manually after form submission*

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ptForm(request.POST)
    latest_entry = pt_data.objects.filter(pt_user=request.user).latest('id')
    if form.is_valid():
        report = form.save(commit=False)
        report.pt_user = request.user
        report.attr = latest_entry.attr
        report.save()
        form = ptForm()
```

> *Note: Replace `.attr` with the attributes you want to update from previous form entry.*

> *Warning: Be careful when user has not filled out a form before. As the `latest_entry` will be empty.*

Comment: This works functionally, however, the fields are populated with the data when users go to fill out a returning form. Its a hidden field in HTML but can be seen on inspecting. Is there a way to populate initial values without giving the user access to the information?

Comment: Using template tags to add the HTML form sections only when this is a returning user hides the information and still allows you to submit the form with the information

Comment: @Austin please see my **Method 2** in my updated answer.

Comment: This method doesn't work because form.is_valid() fails due to not having the required fields before they can be added. I am trying to create a form that can be submitted for new and returning users.